# How can I refresh the data(API) in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Right now I am calling the data from the backend but when the backend updates any value its also not refect in the UI

Later on, In useEffect, I am calling Axios with set interval but it continuously runs in the networks tab so I want when the server updates anything it updates without using set interval.
How can I update the table component?

Comment: Do you want a real-time update feature like the one fireabase firestore ? for your DB

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is something like this:

```js
const [populationData, setPopulationData] = useState([]);
async function fetchData() {
    fetch(
      'https://datausa.io/api/data?drilldowns=Nation&measures=Population'
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) =>
        setPopulationData(res.data)
      );
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

When you will set `populationData` with `setPopulationData` it will trigger a re-render and you should be able to display your props in UI.

If I understood it correctly you are running into an infinite loop of axios requests?
Notice the `[]` as a second argument of `useEffect`? This is going to solve the infinite loop problem for you.

You can read about dependencies and the empty array part here in the doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

PS: you can also use async/await to handle the request. Whichever is better is just an opinion. It's up to you to decide.

Comment: Why do you mix async/await and use of .then at the same time?
Whenever you put await keyword before function, the other line will wait until execution is completed. Async/await was introduced to get rid of .then() pattern.

Comment: You can simply use `const res = await fetch('https...')` and simply do anything with that res on the next line, which will await fetch execution.

Comment: this fetches the data on load, but i don't see how it continually polls for updated data as was requested in the question (he is running axios every x seconds to pull new data)

Comment: For realtime updates `websocket` could be used, but the question is poorly formulated and it is not clear it's indeed what needs to be done. 

`Backend` is briefly mentioned, but what kind of backend? Is it even nodejs? Is it firebase, something else? Can he make changes to the `backend`?

Here is an article covering it in detail for `nodejs` and `react`: 
https://blog.logrocket.com/websocket-tutorial-real-time-node-react/